# Create table query using JDBC doesn't working with different database engines

Tags: java, sql, scala, jdbc

I write a scala program which interoperates with some database engines (for example MySQL, PostgreSQL).

I use JDBC api to handle SQL queries. I use queries to create table, and I want to create a table with the fields given by users, then these fields are names which can contains spaces or words with accent.

For example, create a table dummy with 2 fields, *'column 1'* and *'column 2'* as varchar fields.

Writing this query for MySQL database while preserving the spaces contained in the fields, we need to use backticks in the query like :

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (`column 1` varchar(20), `column 2` varchar(20));
```

In the same way, the right way to write this query for PostgreSQL while preserving the spaces is :

```
CREATE TABLE dummy ("column 1" varchar(20), "column 2" varchar(20));
```

Maybe for another database engine, there is a different way to write this query.

Is there any standard way to write this query with the constrainsts above and using JDBC so that it works with any database engines ?

Thank in advance for your answers.

Comment: You could consider using an ORM tool like Hibernate which would handle some of the database specific nuances in syntax.

Comment: No. But dealing with spaces i column names, and case-sensitive names, is a nightmare. I would just forbid that. Or replace spaces with underscores.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly address your question as asked, but I think that you would be better off not naming your columns this way. I would 'normalize' the column names (by, e.g. replacing spaces with underscores).

The column names should probably not be exposed directly to the users anyway.
If you need 'human readable' names for columns, I would store them in another table. Or, if it is as simple as preserving spaces, just reverse the process, replacing underscores with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you should not use spaces, special characters or reserved words as column or table names. To play it safe you can generally put quotes around table and column names to avoid case-sensitivy issues accross databases.

```
CREATE TABLE "foo" ("id" VARCHAR(32), "bar" VARCHAR(64))
```

According to SQL-99 standard double quotes (") are used to delimit identifiers. Case sensitivy actually relates to the type of database used and it's settings. There are dbs that will upper- or lowercase your table and column names if they are not quoted but sometimes only in `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` commands. Which can lead to runtime errors.

For example `CREATE TABLE foo` might actually create a table named `FOO`. When doing a `SELECT * FROM foo` you might get an error because table `foo` does not exist but table `FOO` does exist. Having worked accross lots of DBMS I tend to use quotes for table and column names.

**The important part is** that you have to stick to writing lowercase or uppercase when using quotes because `"foo"` is not equal to `"FOO"` but `foo` might be equal to `FOO` depending on the used DBMS. Either do lowercase or uppercase but stick to it if you're using quotes.

You should also avoid database specific column types (stick to ANSI SQL whenever possible).

But doing database migrations by hand is very tedious and error-prone. I would suggest to use migration tools (flyway db) or let the migrations get created by libraries like slick.

As you mentioned scala, please have a look at Slick (http://slick.lightbend.com/) which is a great functional database layer for scala. There are others too but that one I use heavily and can recommend it.

Comment: No, quoting the names of your tables, columns, and other identifiers *creates* case-sensitivy issues, not avoids them.